# JwtAuthentication disabled Identity login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, jwt, asp.net-identity

So I added Jwt Authentication to my ASP.NET Core project. The project has two ways of interaction:

1) Directly using the webservice. Uses MVC controller to access and move things around.

2) Separate client.

I added JWT for the client to allow for token generation and request it upon client requests.

For the client side, it is working. However, it was broken on the webservice side. I am using Bootstrap4 and now I can't login using the webpages.

Here are parts of Startup.cs:

```
private class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions> {
  private readonly IOptions<JwtAuthentication> _jwtAuthentication;

  public ConfigureJwtBearerOptions(IOptions<JwtAuthentication> jwtAuthentication) {
    _jwtAuthentication = jwtAuthentication ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(jwtAuthentication));
  }

  public void PostConfigure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options) {
    var jwtAuthentication = _jwtAuthentication.Value;

    options.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAuthentication.ValidIssuer;
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
      ValidateActor = true,
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidIssuer = jwtAuthentication.ValidIssuer,
      ValidAudience = jwtAuthentication.ValidAudience,
      IssuerSigningKey = jwtAuthentication.SymmetricSecurityKey,
      NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
    };
  }
}
```

Then I am using that private class to add authentication:

```
  services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer();
```

Finally,

```
  app.UseAuthentication();
```

Now if I comment out `services.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer()` my webservice will work again and Bootstrap4 will allow me to login and do whatever I want. But the problem with this is that it wont authenticate client program properly.

Is there a way to let Bootstrap4 login be authenticated using the Jwt Authentication method?

Note: _LoginPartial.cshtml is by default:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

The condition `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))` never returns true after I enable authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's best NOT to authenticate Identity using Jwt Authentication due to the headache of passing tokens all around the website which makes it very difficult.

I found this [article](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2) which describes how to have both authentication schemes.

Basically, I replaced this code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer();
```

With this:

```
  services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
  services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg => {
      cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      cfg.SaveToken = true;

      cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtAuthentication:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAuthentication:ValidAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtAuthentication:SecurityKey"]))
      };
    });
```

And now both authentication schemes are working.

This was the best solution in my case because I have two completely separate controllers to do the work:

1) MVC controller: uses Identity Authentication

2) API Controller: uses JWT Authentication